# How to use the Parent as a Constructor parameter of a Child?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, parent-child, composition

I want to be able to write something like this `Subclass sub = new Subclass(parent);`.

Here's a pseudocode illustrating the idea

```java
public class Creature extends Egg {
    public Creature hatch(Egg egg) {
        Creature out = (Creature) egg;
        out.potency = new Random().nextDouble();
        return out;
    }
}
```

It's not possible to make it work exactly like this.

I could of course copy all variables from `egg` to `this` (instance of `Creature`), but I don't want to modify the constructor every time I change variables in `Egg` class.

What would be the easiest way to copy all data from a Parent class instance to a Subclass in a constructor?

Comment: I think that completely beats the purpose of inheritance, a parent should not need to know its children or its capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That a good use case for Composition, not for Inheritance. I.e. instead of extending `Egg` class, you can introduce a property of type `Egg` in the `Creature` class, and refer to it when you need a property that is coming from the egg.

Keep in mind, that although Inheritance is an important principle of the OOP, the Composition should be always considered as a preferred approach (for more information refer to the item *Favor composition over inheritance* of the classic book *"Effective Java"* by Joshua Bloch, former Sun-employee, author of the Collections framework, and many other language features).

Also, since from the logical standpoint only one Creature can be hatched from one Egg you can introduce `boolean` property `hatched` in the `Egg` class to ensure that the same Egg can not be reused to spawn multiple Creatures.

Here's how it might be implemented:

```
public class Creature {
    private Egg egg;
    private double potency;

    private Creature(Egg egg) {
        this.egg = egg;
    }

    public Creature hatch(Egg egg) {
        if (egg.isHatched()) throw new IllegalStateException("This egg has been already hatched");
        
        egg.setHatched();                 // marking the egg as hatched
        
        Creature out = new Creature(egg); // hatching the creature
        out.potency = new Random().nextDouble();
        return out;
    }
}

public class Egg {
    private boolean hatched;
    // some other properties
    
    public void setHatched() {
        this.hatched = true;
    }

    public boolean isHatched() {
        return hatched;
    }
}
```